# Node title get deleted when saving a translation of the node

Tags: i18n-l10n

Not sure if this is issue of the [Title](https://drupal.org/project/title) module which I have enabled, or just a bad configuration.

To reproduce:

1- Create a content type: **My content** and checked **Enabled, with translation**

2- Create a english node with title: **My english node title**. Save

3- Create a translation for that node to french with title:  **My french node title**. Save

4- Now(after I saved the french node) if I go to edit the english node the **title field** is empty

It happens in the other way too. If I edit and save the english node and then I go to edit the french node the **title field** is empty

How can I trace this? It seems a bug to me, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to manage your content type translation at **node level** or **field level** ? You can have a mix of both on the same site if needed, for different content types, but don't mix up within a content type.

If you choose "basic" node translation for content type A, you won't need the [Title module](https://drupal.org/project/title), so if it's enabled/in use for content type B, just **don't** "replace" (`admin/structure/types/manage/content_type_A/fields/replace/title`) the **built in** node title of A by a field.

Then when you translate a node from `node/xxx/translate` then `node/add/content_type_A?translation=xxx&target=lang` , everything should be ok.

Read also [Gábor Hojtsy explanations](http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2011-jan-31/drupal-7039s-new-multilingual-systems-part-4-node-translation) which are still valuable about translation settings, or Randy Fay [Field translation: First steps](http://randyfay.com/content/content-translation-field-translation-drupal-7-first-steps)

Comment: Since I was not using field translation I just disabled the entity_translation module and the problem was gone. Maybe a conflict between title and entity_translation modules.